# Am I going to find Busybox after a Loki update or does it ship with certain packages? If so which ones please so I can avoid it?

Tags: release-loki

I've been having problems with Freya, Ubuntu 16 and Linux Mint over the last few weeks - all boot problems and all something to do with Busybox

This week I installed Loki onto 2 HDD's on my PC. One I updated and customised with packages I like to use and it suddenly refused to boot - Busybox was there and gave me the intramfs prompt.

I rebooted onto the other HDD and ran *dpkg -L busybox* and found it isn't there on the basic installation and my system starts perfectly on that HDD.

I do **not** want Busybox, it seems to be something invented for compact devices such as phones. I read about it and find it's incredibly invasive and also has vulnerabilities that are related to Microsoft.

It has caused me loads of head-banging grief.

Am I going to find Busybox after a Loki update or does it ship with certain packages? If so which ones please so I can avoid it?

I hate it so much.
I looked at Debian iso's on the Debian website and they All have it.

I am looking to keep my elementary system free of it or find another distro that will not include it at all.

Answer (score 0):

Firstly, I don't believe EOS ships with busybox by default, however there are steps you can take that should do what you require.

#### Instructions:

On installing Loki (or now if already installed) `sudo apt-get remove busybox` just to make sure it isn't installed, and if so remove (if it says other packages depend on it, remove them all too).

Next, try adding the below line to: `/etc/apt/preferences`

```
Package: busybox
Pin: release *
Pin-Priority: -1
```

This should stop it ever appearing, and prevent you from installing anything that depends on it.

You should be able to test by running:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install busybox
```

If that doesn't fail, I guess you can look at other options [with this link](https://www.tecmint.com/disable-lock-blacklist-package-updates-ubuntu-debian-apt/) but I think that the above pin should be enough to prevent you from ever installing it.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I think that it sort of takes over initialising things. I'll be careful and will see how that goes though, I would think I can still install things again without it. I've looked at a few distros and they all come with it. Loki seems alright just now. Perhaps it's because I install a few needed packages from gnome.